# I don't know why my social media button won't connect to the link

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-github"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-snapchat"></a>
```

Whenever I replace the "#" with the desired link, the buttons don't work. I haven't been coding for very long at all.

Comment: can you try and pull up the developer tools on the browser and say if clicking on it with a link throws an error ?

Comment: Can you give an example of a link you have tried and explain the outcome you are experiencing to what you expect to happen?

Comment: This is an an example of a link being in the code. <a href="https://www.instagram.com/worldstar/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>

Comment: I would like button to bring me to the link when I press on it.  The button simply does nothing when I click on it.

Comment: Include www. in your links!

Comment: You need the full URL (like `https://instagram.com/foobar`)

Answer (score 0):

Use full URL:

```
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/worldstar/" class="fa fa-instagram">Worldstar</a>
```

You can also use javascript syntax:

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com/worldstar/', '_blank');" class="fa fa-instagram">Worldstar</button>
```

Use '_self' istead of '_blank' if you want the link to open in the same window and not a new tab.